# Problems with Bootstrap 3 Progress Bar in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, css3pie

I'm having problems with the rendering of the **Bootstrap 3.0.3** progress bar in **IE8**. I think `border-radius` is not working and i don't know why. This is how the bar looks like:

[image]

I'm using CSS3PIE 1.0.

`.compatibilidad-IE` is defined in my CSS file and the path is relative to de HTML file. I know this class is working well because y have applied it to other DOM elements in the same HTML and they are rendered as expected.

This is the style class definition:

```
.compatibilidad-IE {
    behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div style="width:200px;">
    <div class="progress compatibilidad-IE" >
        <div class="progress-bar  compatibilidad-IE"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
            <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me!

Thanks.

Comment: `border-radius` does not work in IE. Are you sure that PIE.htc is in the right place?

Comment: Absolutely! I have in the same HTML many `<input>` and `<button>` in wich `border-radius` and `linear-gradient` are being applied correctly!

Comment: If you use developer tools to inspect the progress bar what other classes (or elements) come before .progress or .compatibilidad-IE?

Answer (score -1):

Put your PIE.htc in the root of your webpages.

Use this code:

```
.compatibilidad-IE {
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1;
    behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
```

Or if you have PIE.htc in your js folder use:

```
behavior: url(/js/PIE.htc);
```

This is because you need an absolute path.